# get data from child record(or hyper link) to print in netsuite advanced html pdf

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, html-templates

I am new to netsuite and is working on creating a html template for invoice groups. The group has multiple invoices as lines and you can click on them and navigate to the actual invoice which has a lot more data.

I want to print the invoice group details and also show some data that is only available in the actual invoice level.

[screenshot of invoices under invoice group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0J6p.png)

I can access the invoice number in the group like `record.invoice_details.invoicenum` but I want to get the data under this invoice which can be accessed like `record.item.item_display` if I am in the invoice screen. So I am looking for something like `record.invoice_details.invoicenum.item_display` where I start at the invoice group and make my way down to the invoice items.

Any help here is appreciated. DO let me know if you need any more info here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like `record.invoice_details.invoicenum.item_display` would be considered a multi-level join which NetSuite does not support.  I'm not sure what you meant by "to get the data **under** this invoice" but if it's a value stored on the record itself use the field id in `record.invoice_details.FIELD_ID`.  If it is not on the record, you'll have to add it to the record (could be in a hidden field).  Or you can create use SuiteScript to create a custom function.  Reference Suite Answers [82586](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/82586), [49137](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49137/kw/49137), and [44622](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44622/kw/44622)

Via SuiteScript you can add data to an Advanced PDF template using the
"addCustomDataSource" method on the report object:

```
var invoiceGroupInvoiceReportRows = { groupedinvoices_summary: [<your data>] };
var invoiceDetailReportRows = { invoice_details: [<your data>] };
xmlReport.addCustomDataSource({
    format: render.DataSource.OBJECT,
    alias: 'results',
    data: invoiceGroupInvoiceReportRows
})
```

Then reference that data in the report XML like:

```
<#list results.groupedinvoices_summary as invoice>
...
</#list>
```

Comment: Hey, I am trying to create a custom print template for invoice groups. Now the seeded template only has a few columns. The form also do not have the required columns. So I want to access the actual invoices and get the data from the invoice itself and use it in invoice group template. Invoices under an invoice group is shown in the screenshot for reference.

Comment: I think if Suite Answer Id: 93101 is not relevant then Suite Answer id: 49339 holds the answer, i.e. you must use the SuiteScript 2.0 render module.